# Show that an analytic function defined on unit ball with these properties does not exist

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Show that there does not exist an analytic function 
$F : B(0,1) \to \mathbb{C}-\mathbb{Q} $ with $F(0)=i$ and $F(1/2)=-i$.

I have already used the open mapping theorem to show that if we assume towards a contrdiciton that such an $F$ exists then  we must have $F : B(0,1) \to \mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R} $. I then thought of composing $F$ with the Mobius transformation

$M(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$

that sends the real line to the unit circle and the half upper plane to the unit disc (without the boundary) and is such that $M(F(0))=0$ in an attempt to apply the Schwarz lemma. But I am stuck at this point. Tried to see if I could apply other theorems like the maximum principle but didn't have much progress.

I would prefer a hint or a nudge in the right direction rather than a complete answer. Thank you.

Comment: If $F \colon B(0,1) \to \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is a non-constant holomorphic function, what can you say about $F(B(0,1))$?

Comment: @DanielFischer That $F(B(0,1))$ must be open ? But I already used that to show that $F(B(0,1))$ is contained in $\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$. Is there a way to exploit this further?

Comment: What _else_ can you say about $F(B(0,1))$? Hint: $F$ is __continuous_

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich That $|F(B(0,1))|$ has no maximum?

Comment: Think just about continuity. What properties of sets are preserved under continuous maps?

Comment: @DanielFischer They preserve connectedness. Thank you I see the solution now.